# Как получать координаты в виде объекта, а не массива react-native+expo?

Tags: react-native, геолокация, expo

получаю координаты с помощью expo

```js
let locat = await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('Location',{ accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced, 
            timeInterval: 1000,
            deferredUpdatesInterval: 1000, 
            distanceInterval: 0 }, loc => this.setState({ location:loc }));
```

ответ приходит в виде массива координат

```js
Received new locations Array [
  Object {
    "coords": Object {
      "accuracy": 16.702999114990234,
      "altitude": 0,
      "heading": 0,
      "latitude": 36.2385202,
      "longitude": 120.0500676,
      "speed": 0,
    },
    "timestamp": 1566958984601,
  },
  Object {
    "coords": Object {
      "accuracy": 16.702999114990234,
      "altitude": 0,
      "heading": 0,
      "latitude": 36.2385202,
      "longitude": 120.0500676,
      "speed": 0,
    },
    "timestamp": 1566958984635,
  },
  Object {
    "coords": Object {
      "accuracy": 16.702999114990234,
      "altitude": 0,
      "heading": 0,
      "latitude": 36.2385202,
      "longitude": 120.0500676,
      "speed": 0,
    },
    "timestamp": 1566958989614,
  },
  Object {
    "coords": Object {
      "accuracy": 16.702999114990234,
      "altitude": 0,
      "heading": 0,
      "latitude": 36.2385202,
      "longitude": 120.0500676,
      "speed": 0,
    },
    "timestamp": 1566958994640,
  },
  Object {
    "coords": Object {
      "accuracy": 16.702999114990234,
      "altitude": 0,
      "heading": 0,
      "latitude": 36.2385202,
      "longitude": 120.0500676,
      "speed": 0,
    },
    "timestamp": 1566958999658,
  },
  Object {
    "coords": Object {
      "accuracy": 16.702999114990234,
      "altitude": 0,
      "heading": 0,
      "latitude": 36.2385202,
      "longitude": 120.0500676,
      "speed": 0,
    },
    "timestamp": 1566959004699,
  },
  Object {
    "coords": Object {
      "accuracy": 16.702999114990234,
      "altitude": 0,
      "heading": 0,
      "latitude": 36.2385202,
      "longitude": 120.0500676,
      "speed": 0,
    },
    "timestamp": 1566959009734,
  },
  Object {
    "coords": Object {
      "accuracy": 16,
      "altitude": 0,
      "heading": 0,
      "latitude": 36.2385205,
      "longitude": 120.0500672,
      "speed": 0,
    },
    "timestamp": 1566959010985,
  },
]
```

как получать только один элемент этого массива через определенный период времени?

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь функцией Location.watchPositionAsync